# Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance 50.0/100 is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2

```
String expression = CHEMICAL_REORDERPOINT + "*" + searchRequest.getReorderPercentage() + "/100)";
```

Before :

```
String expression = CHEMICAL_REORDERPOINT + "*" + searchRequest.getReorderPercentage() + "/100)";
```

`searchRequest.getReorderPercentage()` comes dynamically from browser after submit value.
Lets take value for `searchRequest.getReorderPercentage() = 50`

```
so String expression = CHEMICAL_REORDERPOINT*50/100;
```

This is getting populated in a prepared statement of `JDBC` in my application, so to maintain the prepare statement rule i have used in below way:

After :

```
String expression = CHEMICAL_REORDERPOINT + "*?)"
String str = searchRequest.getReorderPercentage() + "/100";
params.add(str)
```

here params is a list from which the parameters will be iterated and will be placed in postion parameters of prepare statement while executing it.

But now i m getting exception like 
 **Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance 50.0/100 is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815**

Pls can any one help me out. Thanks

Comment: this isn't SQL. please change tag

Comment: @LuisLL Looks to me like he is constructing an SQL query, but I agree it would have been better if he included the actual SQL query produced

Comment: Not an expert on jdbc+db2 but... is it legal to specify a parameter using an expression in stead of a value? Isn't it interpreting the parameter as a string so that the resulting sql is " * '50/100' " leading to a conversion error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameterized query string should look like "`whatever is in CHEMICAL_REORDERPOINT * (? / 100)`", and you should set the percentage value using setDouble() or setFloat(), not as a String. Right now you are trying to tell DB2 to multiply whatever by a string, which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess I would say it is an auto conversion issue.

You had something like

```
5 * 50.0 / 100
```

and it worked.

No you have

```
50.0 / 100
```

and it fails.

It seems in the first it converted all operands to integers and in the second it converts them to floating point.  But 100 is not a valid floating point constant.  So change your new output to

```
50.0 / 100.0
```

or

```
50 / 100
```